# DVD+R with H.264 Blu-ray video

Tags: video, dvd, burning, blu-ray, adobe-premiere

I did a video in **Adobe Premiere** of 16 minutes. I want to put the video in a **DVD+R** disc so when a person inserts it in the DVD player connected to the TV, it will begin **automatically**. Therefore I chose to render my video in Premiere as format *H.264 Blu-ray* with preset of *HD 1080i 29.97 (1.33 PAR)*. I put that the *field order* is *Upper First* and that the TV Standard is *NTSC*.

The video was rendered as *final video.m4v* with an extra file *final video.m4v.xmpes* . Now I wanted to burn my *DVD+R* disc with these two files.

I went to my File Explorer and clicked on *DVD RW Drive (F:)*. It opened a screen that says how do I want to use this disc and I chose "*With a CD/DVD player*" (can't be edited). I put these two files in the disc (with the desktop file that was put automatically) and burned the disc!

Afterwards, I put it in the DVD player and the screen in the player shows **"Err"**.

I'm sorry I gave so many information but I don't know which do I need to give so you can help me, I just have one disc left. Maybe the problem is that I put a Blu-ray file in a DVD disc? Which format and preset should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make an authored (menu-less) DVD [using](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/exporting-dvd-or-blu-ray.html) Encore.

Note that the resolution will be 720x480 (NTSC), since DVD-Video doesn't have HD support.

Comment: Why do I need a menu-less video? Why doesn't work just the video alone?

Comment: When you author the DVD in Encore, you want to skip the menu since you wish the video to autoplay once inserted in the DVD player.

Comment: Oh... wow. Thanks. Never would thought that's the way it's done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert with optical technology but I believe your assumption is partially correct. You encoded your video in Blu-ray format, which cannot not be read by your **DVD player**. I have seen posts that say you can burn the Blu-ray files to a DVD like you did, but you're missing the **Blu-ray player** that can actually play it.

I'd take the burning Blu-ray to a DVD part with a grain of salt. Some posts said you have to use a ripping program and some said you could just burn it straight to the disc.

Here is where I read that [information](http://www.bu.edu/comlabs/creating-a-bluray-or-dvd-disc/). I would also assume that burning the Blu-ray to a DVD would give it a bit less quality

Comment: I understand. If I put a correct format video in a **DVD+R** disc that I didn't burn (that I can edit), in the DVD player: will it work?

Comment: @PichiWuana Yeah as long as you write to the DVD in a format your DVD player can read, you'll have no problem.

Comment: I don't know why my DVD continues to show in its screen *Err*...

Comment: @PichiWuana did you make a new disc and it still does that?